# Excel/Access, how to export a query's contents to a pre-existing sheet without breaking references?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

So I have this big Excel workbook that has several references to a sheet (in the same workbook), and this sheet has to be updated periodically from a query in an MS Access database (the code for this I am writing in MS Access VBA).

However I don't know how to export the query to that workbook/worksheet without "replacing" the sheet and messing up all the references. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Please provide what you have so far so that we can help

Comment: I am typing this on a separate laptop so I don't have the code here but I am using transferspreadsheet

Comment: I am using transferspreadsheet  - Don't. Retrive the data from inside excel as a recordset and use range.copyfromrecordset instead. That will overwrite the contents of the cells  in your range without messing up your references

Comment: "as a recordset" -- what do you mean exactly?

Comment: search for opening ADO recordset in vba here (sorry don't know how to put references here) to see sample code. Run the query in Excel and then use the returned recordset.